# What's the effect of Chill-filtering on Whisky?

Tags: whiskey

Some whiskys (for example [Deanston 12](http://deanstonmalt.com/our-whisky/deanston-12-year-old) ) say on their label that they are "Un-Chill filtered" and in the example case follow that up with "exactly as it should be" which implies that there are some negative effects to chill-filtering whisky.

What are the effects (positive and negative) of Chill-Filtering whisky?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The main reason to chill filter a whisky is actually purely cosmetic

Chill filtering is a process that makes sure that a whiskey won't go cloudy if water or ice is added to it.

It is mainly only done as people don't want to see a cloudy whiskey so it is done a a cosmetic touch to make the whiskey more appealing.

Although if a whiskey is above 46% this process is not necessary as the alcohol level will stop the cloudiness from happening.

It is causing a bit of bother with whiskey distillers as people want a natural organic whiskey so they don't want it to go through the process of chill filtering but they also want a nice clear whiskey.

For more information see [Here](http://www.whiskyforeveryone.com/whisky_basics/chill_filtration.html)